# How to get documents by id from subquery in Laravel Jessenger Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using Laravel with jessenger mongodb (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb), and I have the following object collections in mongodb:

```
User: (id,name,email)
```

and

```
Message (from_id,to_id,text)
```

I need to get all users from the to_id corresponding to a given from_id, essentially like a relational join operation `(SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Messages ON Users.id=Messages.from_id WHERE to_id='xxxx')`.

I am using `Message::where('from_id', '=', $user->_id)->get(['to_id'])` to get the id's of the users I need, but now I need the full objects of those id's from the Users collection.... Is it possible to use something like a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup, which are not replacement of join but you can use to get your desired output. Let me know, if below query answer you question or not?

```html
db.User.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Message",
         localField: "id",
         foreignField: "from_id",
         as: "user_message"
       }
  }
  ,{$match:{id:1}}
])
```

Thanks
DC

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how would I use this in Laravel Eloquent/jessenger (ORM) syntax? :)